# Python generators: return yield

Tags: python, generator, yield, coroutine

In the following block of code:

```python
def bottom():  
    # Returning the yield lets the value that goes up the call stack to come right back down.
    return (yield 42)

def middle():  
    return (yield from bottom())

def top():  
    return (yield from middle())

# Get the generator.
gen = top()  
value = next(gen)  
print(value)  # Prints '42'.  
try:  
    value = gen.send(value*2)
except StopIteration as exc:  
    value = exc.value
print(value)  # Prints '84'.
```

1. What does return (yield 42) actually do ? Why not simply return 42
   and why is (yield 42) in parenthesis ?
2. What does he mean by this:
   "Returning the yield lets the value that goes up the call stack to
   come right back" ?
3. Why is [he](https://github.com/brettcannon) using "yield from" in the "top" and
   "middle" functions ?

Comment: `yield` expressions evaluate to whatever value is sent into the generator, e.g. when calling `gen.send(value * 2)` the expression becomes `value * 2`.

Comment: A very thorough explanation of `yield` and generators: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/5463636](http://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/5463636)

Comment: @freginold that actually doesn't address generators as coroutines, which is needed to understand this particular example

Comment: @freginold indeed, you need to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31042491/5014455) answer buried deep in the list of answers to find something that addresses this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that is very good information, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @freginold yeah, unfortunately this is probably what I would consider "advanced" Python, beyond merely "intermediate" (e.g. using generators just to create lazy iterators). It mixes concurrency, probably the most hard to grasp concept in computer science, with probably the most obscure part of Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga are you referring to this chapter: "Cooperative Delegation to Sub-Coroutine with yield from" ? Is that generator concurency ?

Comment: @Liviu I'm not referring to any chapter, I don't know what book you are reading...

Comment: But here is a good [presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf) on the subject.